# How to change background colour of webform?

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm finishing a website that someone else started and there are a few things I can't figure out. It's a Drupal 8 installation and I have administrator permissions, but I've tried every setting I can find in Drupal to change the background colour of the webforms on the site. I checked the web hosting for custom css and I found a file in this location;

```
public_html/themes/our_theme/css
```

And it looks like someone has been editing that file because there's commenting that aren't comments, but code that's commented out. However, when I make changes to that file, nothing happens. That could be because the file seems to be getting minified and saved as another file, which is then read by the browser when a user goes to the website.

Any help?

Comment: disable CSS compression and check whether the CSS file you suppose to hold the styles is really included. If not you should see what other css files are included instead

Comment: Disabling CSS compression seems to have fixed it. Thanks. If you want to write it up as an answer, I'll mark it correct.